# iOS 10.2 callkit error -> [aurioc] 892

Tags: swift2, callkit

I use Callkit with iOS10.0.1 and he works perfectly (outbound and inbound calls).
After update my iPhone7 to iOS 10.2. I heard nothing when i receive an inbound call.

For AudioController :

```
try {
    // Configure the audio session
    AVAudioSession *sessionInstance = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    // we are going to play and record so we pick that category
    NSError *error = nil;
    [sessionInstance setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    XThrowIfError((OSStatus)error.code, "couldn't set session's audio category");

    // set the mode to voice chat
    [sessionInstance setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];
    XThrowIfError((OSStatus)error.code, "couldn't set session's audio mode");

    // set the buffer duration to 5 ms
    NSTimeInterval bufferDuration = .005;
    [sessionInstance setPreferredIOBufferDuration:bufferDuration error:&error];
    XThrowIfError((OSStatus)error.code, "couldn't set session's I/O buffer duration");

    // set the session's sample rate
    [sessionInstance setPreferredSampleRate:44100 error:&error];
    XThrowIfError((OSStatus)error.code, "couldn't set session's preferred sample rate");

    // add interruption handler
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleInterruption:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                               object:sessionInstance];

    // we don't do anything special in the route change notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleRouteChange:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
                                               object:sessionInstance];

    // if media services are reset, we need to rebuild our audio chain
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   addObserver:    self
                                             selector:  @selector(handleMediaServerReset:)
                                                 name:  AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification
                                               object:  sessionInstance];
}

catch (CAXException &e) {
    NSLog(@"Error returned from setupAudioSession: %d: %s", (int)e.mError, e.mOperation);
}
catch (...) {
    NSLog(@"Unknown error returned from setupAudioSession");
}
```

and

```
try {
    // Create a new instance of Apple Voice Processing IO

    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);
    XThrowIfError(AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &_rioUnit), "couldn't create a new instance of Apple Voice Processing IO");

    //  Enable input and output on Apple Voice Processing IO
    //  Input is enabled on the input scope of the input element
    //  Output is enabled on the output scope of the output element

    UInt32 one = 1;
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &one, sizeof(one)), "could not enable input on Apple Voice Processing IO");
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &one, sizeof(one)), "could not enable output on Apple Voice Processing IO");

    // Explicitly set the input and output client formats
    // sample rate = 44100, num channels = 1, format = 32 bit floating point

    CAStreamBasicDescription ioFormat = CAStreamBasicDescription(44100, 1, CAStreamBasicDescription::kPCMFormatFloat32, false);
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &ioFormat, sizeof(ioFormat)), "couldn't set the input client format on Apple Voice Processing IO");
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &ioFormat, sizeof(ioFormat)), "couldn't set the output client format on Apple Voice Processing IO");

    // Set the MaximumFramesPerSlice property. This property is used to describe to an audio unit the maximum number
    // of samples it will be asked to produce on any single given call to AudioUnitRender
    UInt32 maxFramesPerSlice = 4096;
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFramesPerSlice, sizeof(UInt32)), "couldn't set max frames per slice on Apple Voice Processing IO");

    // Get the property value back from Apple Voice Processing IO. We are going to use this value to allocate buffers accordingly
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(UInt32);
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitGetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFramesPerSlice, &propSize), "couldn't get max frames per slice on Apple Voice Processing IO");

    // We need references to certain data in the render callback
    // This simple struct is used to hold that information

    cd.rioUnit = _rioUnit;
    cd.muteAudio = &_muteAudio;
    cd.audioChainIsBeingReconstructed = &_audioChainIsBeingReconstructed;

    // Set the render callback on Apple Voice Processing IO
    AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallback;
    renderCallback.inputProc = performRender;
    renderCallback.inputProcRefCon = NULL;
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &renderCallback, sizeof(renderCallback)), "couldn't set render callback on Apple Voice Processing IO");

    // Initialize the Apple Voice Processing IO instance
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitInitialize(_rioUnit), "couldn't initialize Apple Voice Processing IO instance");
}

catch (CAXException &e) {
    NSLog(@"Error returned from setupIOUnit: %d: %s", (int)e.mError, e.mOperation);
}
catch (...) {
    NSLog(@"Unknown error returned from setupIOUnit");
}
```

and i have this in my log :

```
[aurioc] 892: failed: '!pri' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>)
Error returned from setupIOUnit: 561017449: couldn't initialize Apple Voice Processing IO instance
```

do you have an idea ?

Comment: We are also seeing a similar problem. According to https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/169511#169511, moving the configureAudioSession to different places worked for me. It didn't work for us.

Answer (score 0):

Enable your sound devices after Audio session activate. Write your sound enable call in audio session activation call back. You can also use block to invoke from audio session for answer / unhold / etc.